# Calling a def from a thread

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Does any one know how to call a def form a thread.

Clock Program:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from time import sleep
import threading

class MyThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def mclock(): # function that it can't call
        x = 1
        z = 0
        while x != -1:
            Label(mGui,text = str(x) + "second(s)").pack()
            x = x+1
            sleep(1)
            if x == 60:
                x = 1
                z = z+1
            Label(mGui, text= str(z) + " minute(s) has past.").pack()
            return
        return

MyThread().start()

mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry("300x200+100+100")
mGui.title("Jono's Clock")

menubar = Menu(mGui)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Clock",command = mclock) # can't use function

menubar.add_cascade(label = "File",menu = filemenu)
mGui.config(menu = menubar)

mGui.mainloop()
```

If any one sees any other errors please state. I am also using windows 7 and python 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in the code you've posted, and I'm not sure exactly what you intended with them, so here's an overview of how to run stuff from threads.

If you want your thread to run your own code from a custom thread class, the usual way to do that is to put the code in a method named `run`, which will be executed automatically when the thread is started:

```
import threading

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # do your stuff here
        print("Hello World")

MyThread().start()
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a class, you can create your function at the top level of your module, and pass it as an argument to `threading.Thread`'s constructor:

```
def my_function():
    print("Hello World")

threading.Thread(target=my_function).start()
```

Note that you often want to keep a reference to the thread object, rather than letting it go as the code above does. This requires you to use two lines to create and then start the thread:

```
thread = MyThread() # or the alternative version
thread.start()
```

This lets you later do:

```
thread.join()
```

Which ensures that the thread has finished its work.

Comment: That has helped me understand but i'm not sure still so I have put the full code up instead of the example.

Comment: I think you want to make your thread class word like my code, then make your menu option create the `Thread` object and start it. There's no built-in way to run a function in another thread, except by starting a new thread with that function as its target, or with a bunch of code to implement a message passing system between the threads that can include jobs to run.